# Place to ask for feedback on questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am pretty new here. Sometimes I ask a question and it's pretty successful, but sometimes I get barely any upvotes and no answers. The problem is, I'm not sure what I'm doing right when it works and what I'm doing wrong when it does not. I wonder if there's a place where we can show a question and ask for feedback, not on the content of the question itself, but on how other perceive the way you asked the question.

Comment: The associated chat room comes to mind...

Comment: ...which can be reached by [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) or the "chat" link next to your username at the top of the screen (the room is called "Mathematics").

Comment: If you have a specific issue with a particular question (i.e. appreciably more than just "I have no idea what I'm doing wrong"), meta is not the wrong place.

Comment: The chat is a good idea, by the way, but I'll acknowledge that it is sometimes difficult to get help in there.  Only a few of us are chat regulars.

Comment: I've personally found that the #math channels on Freenode and EFNet tend to be a lot busier than the mathematics chat room here. That's no guarantee someone there can/will help you, of course.